# How to well manage a build environment for different target?

Tags: android, build, android-source, java

I'm trying to build different version AOSP and android in ubuntu 14.04. However, I need to switch between different versions of OpenJDK and JAVA SE JDK.

I know I can use `update-alternative` to deal with different installation. But, JAVA SE JDK doesn't appear in `update-alternative`. It's just the contents of a tar ball.

Could anyone suggest a better to deal with different tools for building different targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your JDK installation into `update-alternative` manually.

How you can achieve that:

- [download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) JDK you need, e.g. `jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin`
- extract it; for example, `chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin && ./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin`
- move it in the place you want; personally I prefer `/opt`, so `sudo mv jdk1.6.0_45 /opt`
- you can skip this step, but I'd recommend using symbolic links `sudo ln -fs /opt/jdk1.6.0_45 /opt/jdk1.6`
- add manually this version `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.6/bin/java 1`

*Note*: I'm using symbolic links there.

Then you can always change current JDK with

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`.

And then you can check current version of Java being used in the system.

```
>java - version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

More information you can find in [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) of `update-alternatives`.

Answer (score 2):

By default when you build AOSP it will use your JAVA_HOME which is really frustrating when they are stuck on 1.6 and everyone else is using 1.7.

AOSP will look for an environment variable ANDROID_JAVA_HOME before it builds, so you can set this prior to building and have it point at a different location. This doesn't seem to work on all versions of Android, it definitely does not work on my Marshmallow build, but if it does work it might be more convenient for you.

Go and manually pick up the version of java you need from Oracle, and then find some convenient way to call `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/` . I always use 1.6 because I am not building master yet so I just put it into my .bashrc, but you could just put it in a build script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Editing envsetup.sh is a good idea. It keeps my system clean. However I don't need to use old JDK on my system.

Comment: export `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/` (not `ANDROID_JAVA_HOME`) was enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to switch between JDK version which is not coming in `update-alternative`. I already had JDK 7 and I want to switch to KDK 6. I had downloaded JDK 6 as .bin and installed. But it is not shown in update-alternative. At last I found the solution which is worked for me.

I installed update-java-0.5b which will open GUI which is useful to switch between JDK version.

```
wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/update-java-0.5b
chmod +x update-java-0.5b
sudo ./update-java-0.5b
```

Hope it will help!!